# C code crashes (no idea why)

Tags: c

Basically I'm a beginner coder and this is what I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
system("COLOR 0A");

char playerName[13];
char playerGender;
int playerAge;

printf("Please input your name and age!\nName: ");
scanf("%s", playerName);
printf("Age (from 18 to 50): ");
scanf("%d", &playerAge);

label:
if(playerAge > 18 && playerAge < 50)
{

    printf("What gender are you, M(male) or F(female): ");
    scanf("%c", playerGender);

    gender:
    if(playerGender == 'M' || playerGender == 'F'){

        printf("Okay, so your name is %s, you're %d years old and you're a %s.", playerName, playerAge, playerGender);
    }else{
        printf("Try again.\n\n"
           "What gender are you, M(male) or F(female): ");
           scanf("%c", playerGender);
           goto gender;
    }
}else{

        printf("Wrong, try again.\n"
               "Age (from 18 to 50): ");
        scanf("%d", &playerAge);
        goto label;
}


return 0;
}
```

When I put the required age to continue, it crashes on the `scanf` for the `playerGender`. Right after it shows me the question about my gender? Where is my mistake?

Comment: The main problem is using `scanf` for user input.

Comment: Even though you are a beginner, you had the should-be-common sense to include your complete program and a description of its behavior.  This is very good!

Comment: Learn not to use goto from the start.

Comment: @melpomene Not necessarily, you can specify the width for `%s` like so: `%15s`.

Comment: @szczurcio This doesn't fix the main problem, which is using `scanf`.

Comment: @melpomene This (using `%s` without specifying the buffer width) is the only problem with `scanf` IMO. What else do you suggest if I want to read an integer from `stdin`? Could you explain why you think using `scanf` is wrong?

Comment: @szczurcio Users make mistakes. Error detection with scanf is hard or impossible. Error recovery with scanf is impossible. If you want sane behavior, read whole lines (e.g. with `fgets`) and process them afterwards.

Answer (score 10):

try:

```
scanf("%c", &playerGender);
```

instead of

```
scanf("%c", playerGender);
```

as scanf takes a pointer and not a reference to the variable you are trying to fill.

Answer (score 0):

I am also beginner but I think that you need to write this`scanf("%s", playerName);` like this`scanf("%12s", playerName);`

BTW let me know if that works.

Comment: This only explicitly tells `scanf` that the string to take consists of 12 characters. It prevents buffer overflow in case the user input overreaches the length of the array he is storing to and it is of 12 bytes.